# httpresponse not rendering the html page

Tags: python, django

I'm a newbie to Django and created a sample project with an app:

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse,Http404
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.template import Context
from django.template.loader import get_template

def main_page(request):
  template = get_template('main_page.html')
  variables = Context({
    'head_title': u'Django Bookmarks',
    'page_title': u'Welcome to Django Bookmarks',
    'page_body': u'Where you can store and share bookmarks!'
  })
  output = template.render(variables)
  print 'output',output
  return HttpResponse(output)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from bookmarks.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^$',main_page),
        (r'^user/(\w+)/$',user_page),
        #(r'login/$','django.contrib.auth.views.login')
)
```

main_page.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{head_title}}</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{page_title}}</h1>
        <p>{{page_body}}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I print the output variable, I see everything perfectly all right but when I run the server and point to the page, I see a blank page.

Comment: Do you see anything when you view the source of the page?

Comment: <html>
 <head>
  
  <title>Django Bookmarks</h1>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Welcome to Django Bookmarks</h1>
  <p>Where you can store and share bookmarks!</p>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: The source above looks perfect but not sure why everything is blank

Comment: See to the `title` tag. It is not closed

Comment: thats the problem..thanks guyz,,

Comment: @soon: you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the closing tag `</title>`
Your template should look like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{head_title}}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{page_title}}</h1>
        <p>{{page_body}}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```